# Un-escaping characters with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I'm removing certain characters from the string by substituting them:

```
% -> %%
: -> %c
/ -> %s
```

The string "%c" is properly escaped into %%c. However when I try to reverse it back with str_replace( array('%%','%c','%s'), array('%',':','/'), $s)  it converts it into ":". That's proper behaviour of str_replace as per documentation, that's why I'm looking into solution with Regular Expressions.

Please suggest, what should I use to properly decode escaped string. Thank you.

Comment: does it do it in the order of the array?  I'm not sure, what if you changed the array to put the % last. str_replace(array('%c', '%s', %%'), array(':', '/', '%"))

Comment: @stephenbayer Sorry, miss-read your reply first time. Looks like a good solution, let me try to see if it works in all cases.

Comment: @stephenbayer no it's not working, it produces %: instead.

Comment: @romaninsh: I'm a little confused: ":" becomes "%c", which is then escaped to "%%c". Then you want to un-escape _that_ back to "%c", correct? Because from your "str_replace" arguments it seems you're trying to go all the way back to the original string - and you say that's what it does, too.

Comment: @Flambino, no the original string was "%c" which turns into "%%c" when escaping. It should turn back to "%c" if un-escaped. I was having problem with un-escaping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the replacement for all escape sequences at once and not successively:

```
preg_replace_callback('/%([%cs])/', function($match) {
    $trans = array('%' => '%', 'c' => ':', 's' => '/');
    return $trans[$match[1]];
}, $str)
```

Comment: Works with minor modification: 
    preg_replace_callback('/%[%cs]/', function($match) {
        $trans = array('%%' => '%', '%c' => ':', '%s' => '/');
        return $trans[$match[0]];
    }, $str)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) pipeline (with a temporary marker):

```
<?php

$escaped = "Hello %% World%c You'll find your reservation under %s";

echo preg_replace("/%TMP/", "%",
        preg_replace("/%s/", "/", 
            preg_replace("/%c/", ":", 
                preg_replace("/%%/", "%TMP", $escaped)));

echo "\n";

# Output should be
# Hello % World: You'll find your reservation under /

?>
```

Comment: try $escaped = "Hello %%c";
and you will get "Hello :", which is the exact problem I'm having. I should be getting "Hello %c";

Comment: @romaninsh: your problem can be solved with a temporary marker (see my edits).

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comment (that you want to go from "%%c" to "%c", and not from "%%c" straight to ":"), you can use Gumbo's method with a little modification, I think:

```
$unescaped = preg_replace_callback('/%(%[%cs])/', function($match) {
    return $match[1];
}, $escaped);
```